# Best practice in what to include within a base class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having difficulty finding a best practice in C# for 'base' classes.

Is it true that base classes should only contain variables/properties that are used by EVERYTHING that inherits it?

My example is a property is used by 3 out of the 7 classes that inherit the base class.

```
public class UpgradeBase
{
   Public bool IsToggleable { get; set; } = false;
}

public class UpgradeBuilding : UpgradeBase
{
   //This class needs to access IsToggleable
}

public class UpgradeScience : UpgradeBase
{
   //This class does NOT need to access IsToggleable and never uses it
}
```

Should I be only including this property in the classes that will be using it (the 3 out of 7 classes that actually need this property), or is it 'ok' to define it in the base class (even though 4 out of 7 won't ever care about it)?

Comment: You would never introduce a base class to introduce a property. Instead you would define an interface. Classes usually contain logic (methods).

Comment: @BionicCode I'm not sure where you're coming from. Classes are commonly used for containing data, and they're commonly used for logic. Sometimes both at the same time. A base class is a perfectly fine place to put a property that all inheriting classes should also have.

Comment: @mason *"Classes are commonly used for containing data, and they're commonly used for logic."* - this is beside the point. I didn't deny this. But this is a special case where a *base* class is used only to define a property that certain classes should have - a classic contract, a classic case to introduce an interface. Inheritance is a very problematic concept. If you want classes to have a particular property, an interface is the right way to go. If you want to reuse logic/behavior a common base class will do it. In general, good class design avoids inheritance in favor of composition.

Comment: @BionicCode Your statement of "You would never introduce a base class to introduce a property" is false. They're commonly used for that purpose. So, please remove your inaccurate statement. If you want to say something along the lines of "in this case, using a base class for your property wouldn't make sense because <reasons>" then that's fine.

Comment: Name the class. Think of its purpose, how it would best be used. Does that class' relationship with the "base class candidate" sound more like "is-a" or "has-a"? If the class _is a_, then you may consider inheritance. Otherwise, compose.

Comment: I am surprised that nobody noticed that OP's code states **THIS** class needs to access IsToggleable .... in hat case I would rather have the base class and a `protected bool IsToggleable {get; set;}` and not expose this property to the outside world at all ... which is what an interface would be for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use base classe for class who need to implement the same properties / methods, and use interface on your derived classe who need "special properties"

```
public class UpgradeBase
{

// Implement common properties and method
    }

public interface IToggleable 
{
   bool IsToggleable { get; set; }
}

public class UpgradeBuilding : UpgradeBase, IToggleable
{
   //This class needs to access IsToggleable
   public bool IsToggleable { get; set; } // Interface implementation
}

public class UpgradeScience : UpgradeBase
{
   //This class does NOT need to access IsToggleable and never uses it
}
```

Comment: I am still quite new to C# programming and never understood (or took the time to understand) interfaces and how they should be used. This does sound like the best approach for the properties that are used by more than 1 class but not all.

Comment: @MickyD There are cases where an interface does not define methods but properties. This is especially the case for framework related interfaces, where the framework needs to set/tag client objects that participate in the framework's infrastructure. WPF's `INotifyPropertyChnaged` is a good example. Or the `IAsyncResult`. Interfaces in general are just a contract that guarantee that the implementor defines particular members.

Comment: @MickyD The whole "is-a", "has-a" or "can-do" idioms are helpful for beginners but they are not capturing the whole concept or possibilities. Those idioms try to describe a relationship but not patterns or best practices.

Comment: @MickyD In terms of polymorphic behavior, we can say that an interface also describes a "is-a" relationship. Although an interface does not provide classic inheritance.

Comment: @MickyD Interfaces can have many purposes. From a simple "can-do" contract and enabling of polymorphism to abstract design principles like dependency inversion.

Comment: @MickyD  *"you will realise that INotifyPropertyChnaged represents an event contract that is meant to be utilised in event sinks. You've been doing it for all these years without realising"* - You like to bend reality until it fits your need to troll otherpeople. I gave you an example of an interface that does not contain methods because you claimed that there is a rule that *"interfaces also includes methods"*, implying that this is mandatory. Then what about IAsyncResult? You ignored it completely because it doesn't fit your arguments? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man do you remember?

Comment: @MickyD Be blessed

Comment: And now if you need an `UpgradeEnvironment` which is `IToggleable`, you're going to have to re-implement the field and any accessor methods - or inherit from `UpgradeBuilding`. This doesn't solve the general case.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, a class should only include things that it needs - whether that's in a base class or a descendant class.

I'd probably add a second "base" class that adds the isToggleable feature, and let those classes that need it derive from that intermediate ancestor.

Something like:

```
public class UpgradeBase
{

}

public class UpgradeToggleable : UpgradeBase
{
   public bool IsToggleable { get; set; } = false;
}

public class UpgradeBuilding : UpgradeToggleable
{
   //This class needs to access IsToggleable
}

public class UpgradeScience : UpgradeBase
{
   //This class does NOT need to access IsToggleable and never uses it
}
```

However, doing this for one field is a bit of overkill. Be wary of creating a "god class" that implements everything that every descendant *might* need. That is a good way to wind up with an unmaintainable mess.

Another approach is to favor composition over inheritance. Common functionality that doesn't fit well in a strict hierarchy could be implemented in its own component class. Classes that need those features could include a field of that component type. This is one of the ideas behind so-called Entity/Component/System architectures.

Comment: This is a classic scenario for an interface. You would never use inheritance to introduce properties of any kind.

Comment: @BionicCode **never** is basically **always** wrong when it comes about coding ^^ It depends ... there are circumstances where this might be necessary ;) In Unity (which this question is tagged with) e.g. when it is about editor scripting it i often required because interfaces are not serialized => you need to have a base class for your types if you want to implement a common Inspector drawer for them or reference them in serialized fields etc

Comment: Since OP's code says `This class needs to access IsToggleabl` .. not an outside class but **THIS** class I would rather say there should be a base class with an `protected bool IsToggleable {get; set;}` rather than an interface which exposes it to the outside world ;)

Comment: @derHugo Yes, there are reasons for and against either solution depending on the details of the problem. We don't have enough details to answer this.

Comment: @BionicCode ... then why did you .. and with a quite biased statement ;)

Comment: @BionicCode using an interface doesn't resolve the implementation issue. Sure, one could come up with a set of N interfaces, each of which describe some independent features, but... that's going to turn into mess pretty quickly. And, again, it doesn't answer the question at hand. Where should the interface be implemented? In the base class? Further down in the hierarchy? In each terminal child class? This is just swapping one problem for another.

Comment: `You would never use inheritance to introduce properties of any kind.` Yeah, that's simply incorrect. Properties are syntax sugar for fields with getters and setters. Your statement means that fields have no place in inheritance. Heaven forbid I should require a common field, like "Name" or "ID".

Answer (score 0):

> "Is it true that base classes should only contain variables/properties
> that are used by EVERYTHING that inherits it?"

Not really. Base classes are "normal" classes. A base class is simply a superclass of a subclass. They contain any kind of member. Like classes in general, they must implement everything to satisfy their responsibility.

The logic of a base class will be inherited by its subclasses so that they can reuse the functionality.

If a `Vehicle` has an `Engine` and can `Move()`, then it can be the base class of a `Car`, `Truck`, `Airplane`, `Train` etc.

As you can see, a subclass *extends* its base class. Following a good class design, subclasses should not inherit useless members. For example the `Airplane` class should not inherit the `Dive()` functionality because it is of no use. Your class design must respect such cases. It would make more sense to redesign the inheritance tree and introduce a base class for marine vessels and air vessels.

Ideally, the subcalsses don't know the details about what they are inheriting. Some functionality must be overridden (virtual members) to adjust to the more specialized subclass. The idea is to encapsulate the logic that is shared amongst related types.

You should always consider to define a base class abstract, especially if it requires to be derived from in order to operate meaningful.

Inheritance is a fundamental in object oriented programming. You will find enough resources on the web like eBooks, blogs or tutorials to teach you.

> "Should I be only including this property in the classes that will be
> using it (the 3 out of 7 classes that actually need this property), or
> is it 'ok' to define it in the base class (even though 4 out of 7
> won't ever care about it)?"

You should define an interface `IToggleable`. Then implement this interface on those types that need to be toggleable.

Comment: @MickyD *" If an interface is only ever implemented and never used elsewhere"* - please stop making up stories. I do not discuss about assumptions. You should understand that there is no rule where to use interfaces what for. If a type needs a particular property in order to participate in my infrastructure then I can force it to implement a property. Some call it contract. Not sure why you believe that this is not allowed. Inheritance is just one solution. And it is highly subject to personal opinion whether or not inheritance is a good design choice in general. Not sure if you are trolling.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re thinking in terms of a “base” class, then I’d think the base class would be just that - the class that only cares and knows about itself. It should be minimalistic in that it only includes those features that make it viable.

When it comes to inheriting from the base class, my train of thought is to determine if a derived class needs to override or heavily add to base functionality, or whether a derived class simply needs to include a ‘characteristic’ feature. I refer you to your example of some classes requiring a `IsToggleable` property, and the knowledge that only a few items would need this detail. That could be seen as a ‘characteristic’ of a particular class, but not a driving piece of functionality.

This is where an Interface would come in to play. Let’s define an interface to describe this ‘characteristic’:

```cs
public interface IToggleable
{
    // Define a readable property.
    bool isToggleable { get; }
}
```

Now your example cases would look like:

```cs
public class UpgradeBase
{
   // core base features ..
}

public class UpgradeBuilding : UpgradeBase, IToggleable
{
   public bool isToggleable { get; private set; }
}

public class UpgradeScience : UpgradeBase
{
   // ..
}
```

We could even extend the idea of a ‘characteristic’ by defining a new interface:

```cs
public interface IMovable { }
```

If we now applied that interface to a derived class:

```cs
public class NewClass : UpgradeBase, IMoveable
{
    // a UpgradeBase that is also a IMoveable
}
```

As an example, in our code, we can now store a list of `UpgradeBase`, and check to see if any of them are also `IMoveable` like this:

```cs
// Populate this list with all UpgradeBase and derived class instances
List<UpgradeBase> list;

foreach ( var item in list )
{
    if ( item is IMoveable )
    {
        // this item is moveable.
    }

}
```

Now, this is not definitive, and doesn’t state what the “best practice” should be, but it does illustrate another possibility and train of thought.